# The Urban Vpn setup wizard ended prematurely on window 11

Tags: vpn

When I was trying to install Urban Vpn, I received the next message
Urban Vpn Setup Wizard ended prematurely. OpenVPN Connect Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time, run Setup Wizard again.

Click the Finish button to exit Setup Wizard

[image: Error]

I run window 11

Comment: Provide the installation log for the application

Comment: @Ramhound [link](https://i.imgur.com/F2b84jT.png)

Comment: @Ramhound even id 11708

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That’s the event log for Windows, looking for the installation log, generated by the installer.

Comment: @Ramhound how to looking for the installation log

Comment: Don’t particularly trust the website where the installer is located, so you will have to find the log by yourself, but make sure your running it as an Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound i run urban as an Adminstrator, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i find how fix this problem. tap-windows driver not corectly install in system. Uninstall tapv9 in u device Manager. https://build.openvpn.net/downloads/releases/ download tap-windows-9.24.2-I601-Win10.exe   this, install and try install urban vpn again. GL
sorry for my bad english)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Open Device Manager

Remove Tap-v9 network adapter

Go https://build.openvpn.net/downloads/releases/latest/

openvpn-install-latest-stable-win10 download , install and try again setup UrbanVpn